# creating a new column with unique id numbers

Tags: r, data-manipulation

My data frame looks like this, except there are actually 24 items total for each participant and 99 participants in total. There are also 3 levels to the 'Class' variable 'a', 'b', and 'c'.

```
First  Last  Class  Item  Answer
bob    smith a      1     b
bob    smith a      2     a
bob    smith a      3     a
jane   jones a      1     c
jane   jones a      2     a
jane   jones a      3     b
```

What I want is to create a column 'Unique_ID' column like the one below:

```
Unique_ID First  Last  Class  Item  Answer
1a        bob    smith a      1     b
1a        bob    smith a      2     a
1a        bob    smith a      3     a
2a        jane   jones a      1     c
2a        jane   jones a      2     a
2a        jane   jones a      3     b
```

I would like the 'Class' they are a member of the be included in the ID number.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: what if you have two individuals with the same name in a Class, or can we assume that you don't?

Comment: I happen to know that there aren't any, because it's not a huge dataset and I've checked manually. I guess if their is a way to check that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming combination of First and Last name is unique you can create a unique ID as follows.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Name = paste(First, Last), 
         Unique_ID = paste0(match(Name, unique(Name)), Class))

#  First  Last Class Item Answer       Name Unique_ID
#1   bob smith     a    1      b  bob smith        1a
#2   bob smith     a    2      a  bob smith        1a
#3   bob smith     a    3      a  bob smith        1a
#4  jane jones     a    1      c jane jones        2a
#5  jane jones     a    2      a jane jones        2a
#6  jane jones     a    3      b jane jones        2a
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner in base R that should accomplish the task:

```r
within(df, Unique_ID <- paste0(as.numeric(factor(paste(First, Last))), Class))
#>   First  Last Class Item Answer Unique_ID
#> 1   bob smith     a    1      b        1a
#> 2   bob smith     a    2      a        1a
#> 3   bob smith     a    3      a        1a
#> 4  jane jones     a    1      c        2a
#> 5  jane jones     a    2      a        2a
#> 6  jane jones     a    3      b        2a
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% group_by(First, Last) %>% 
+   mutate(Id = as.character(cur_group_id())) %>% 
+   mutate(Unique_ID = paste0(Id, Class)) %>% 
+   select(-Id) %>% relocate(6,1:5)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   First, Last [2]
  Unique_ID First Last  Class  Item Answer
  <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
1 1a        bob   smith a         1 b     
2 1a        bob   smith a         2 a     
3 1a        bob   smith a         3 a     
4 2a        jane  jones a         1 c     
5 2a        jane  jones a         2 a     
6 2a        jane  jones a         3 b     
>
```